# filtering out some elements in matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (matrix). I want to filter out those lists in my matrix with even one 0 and export the results to a .txt file.

input example:

```
[['ENSG00000137288.5', '0,803921621', '0', '0,435897439', '1,384615397', '0,894736842', '1,151515086', '1,25', '1,2'], ['ENSG00000116032.5', '1,531746311', '2,67857148', '2', '3,0250002', '1,758620722', '1,571428459', '1,028571488', '1,294117703'], ['ENSG00000167578.12', '1,615720507', '2,21323528', '3,308642104', '3,934426129', '1,843137535', '0', '3,108108197', '3,33333321']]
```

output example which would be one of the rows in .txt file:

```
ENSG00000116032.5, 1,531746311, 2,67857148, 2, 3,0250002, 1,758620722, 1,571428459, 1,028571488, 1,294117703
```

thanks

Comment: Show your coding attempts please

Comment: I want to filter out those lists in my matrix with even one 0, this is not clear

Comment: data format is a list of lists. inner lists have some numbers. if one of the numbers is 0 then I don't need the inner list and I want to remove it. and after removing those inner lists I want to export the matrix to a text file in which each inner list would be a line.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method if helps:-

```
    a = [['ENSG00000137288.5', '0,803921621', '0', '0,435897439', '1,384615397', '0,894736842', '1,151515086', '1,25', '1,2'], ['ENSG00000116032.5', '1,531746311', '2,67857148', '2', '3,0250002', '1,758620722', '1,571428459', '1,028571488', '1,294117703'], ['ENSG00000167578.12', '1,615720507', '2,21323528', '3,308642104', '3,934426129', '1,843137535', '0', '3,108108197', '3,33333321']]

    b = filter(lambda x : False if x.count('0') > 0 else x, a)

    print "\n".join([" ".join(item) for item in b])

    #op = 'ENSG00000116032.5 1,531746311 2,67857148 2 3,0250002 1,758620722 1,571428459 1,028571488 1,294117703'
```

Use this output to write in txt file.